# Changing font automatically on specific words (e.g. Java keywords) in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I'm making my own study guide for the [Sun Certified Java Associate](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/newtojava/certification-140469.html) exam. Basically, what I am doing is:

1. Reviewing the stuff on the [McGraw-Hill's study guide](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1206507), and then
2. Typing up notes about the stuff I need to review or new things.

It's going pretty well, but there's one problem: It's *really* annoying to have to change the font to Consolas every time I want to have some code or a keyword stand out. The code I guess I have to change myself, but is there any way of letting Word know that I want a certain word's font changed?

*NB: I am not asking for syntax highlighting.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to create yourself a SmartTag which will detect your keyword as it's typed and perform the appropraite action.

You can learn about SmartTags from the following sites

- [Smart Tag Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159662%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
- [MSDN tutorial on setting up a CSharp Language Recognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168721%28v=office.11%29)

This is most likely the only way to do this however creating smart tags is no five minute job so I think you may want to do this one manually still.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a VBA macro to change the font at the insertion point (the current location you're at in the file) with the press of a hotkey. That might be slightly easier than clicking through the font list dropdown.

You can start with this KB article, but you'll need to adapt the code a bit: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209251